# Scaling down each page when printing using PostScript

Tags: scale, postscript

I have a pdf file which needs to be converted to postscript ( using pdf2ps ) and sent to an old ( Lanier 2145 ) printer. This file has a code at the very bottom of one of the pages, which unfortunately is being cut off.

After spending a long time mucking about with CUPS trying to get it to scale, we have given up and starting to manipulate the actual ps file.

I can scale the pages using

```
<</Install { .80 .80 scale } bind >> setpagedevice
```

However, the scaling is being locked to the bottom left hand corner rather than scaling from the center. This means that the very bottom of the page is still cut off, no matter what the scale.

How can you set where the scaling is done from? I would prefer to scale from the center, but could live with scaling from the top.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder: Can't CUPS print PDF to a PostScript printer (doing the conversion on the fly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a translate in the procedure and move the origin.  For example:

```
<</Install { 18 18 translate .80 .80 scale } bind >> setpagedevice
```